# Is it generally accepted to implement your own random functions ? (C++)

Tags: c++, function, c++11, random, stl

Suppose you are working on a (serious) project that requires random numbers.

Lines like:

```
int num = rand() % 6 + 5; //random number between 5 - 10
```

are (obviously) not going to appear there. The C++11 header `<random>` beats this old C-Style without any doubts.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 engine(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> generate(5, 10);
int num = generate(engine);
```

But when working in a group, I can see 2 problems with this methode:

- The Syntax is wierd and hard to read.
- It's too complex for such an often simple task.

So it would be really nice to have a function (based on this methode) looking like this:

```
int getRandom(int range_begin, int range_end);
```

As far as i'm concerned, there is no such STL function. So I'm asking for your experience: would it be ok to implement this function on your own? Maybe export into a seperate header, then overload it for doubles and float etc.
I am asking this question, because in this modern C++ time, where it's standard to use STL functions, this is a situation where the syntax actually forces you to implement on your own. Thanks for your help & experience on this topic.

EDIT: in the end I am asking whether such an implementation always will happen (sooner or later) in any project that handles random numbers.

Comment: You don't need anyone's permission to implement a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the key goals of C++ is to make it easy to write domain-specific abstractions; if you're writing code that uses a particular form of random number generation frequently, by all means encapsulate that in an appropriate function.

Comment: +1, really, this is just common sense in programming, not specific to RNG - if you write code that does the same task code all the time, by all means encapsulate that in an appropriate function.

Answer (score 1):

There's [`randint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/randint) in TS 2, but it probably won't make it into C++17.

So for now it makes sense to implement your own if you can't/won't use `<experimental/...>`. Consider using `thread_local` engine though.

```
int getRandom(int range_begin, int range_end)
{
    thread_local std::mt19937 engine(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> generate(range_begin, range_end);
    return generate(engine);
}
```

It still initializes `engine` with only 32 bits of randomness on most architectures, but this may very well be enough for you.